# Should I treat objects from a "dumb" managed wrapper over a native COM dll as unmanaged resources?

Tags: c#, silverlight, com, resources

My managed application consumes legacy functionality exposed by a native COM dll via a managed wrapper. I cannot change the COM dll nor its managed wrapper.

- The managed wrapper is in essence automatically generated by a script, given the COM type declarations as input.
- The COM layer will internally access network, file system, graphics and other unmanaged resources.
- Most managed types in the wrapper are created using factory-like methods.
- Most managed types in the wrapper has no way of manually trigger clean-up or resource-release.
- No managed type in the wrapper implements IDisposable.
- No managed type in the wrapper explicitly implements a finalizer.

I feel that I'm missing a lot in my application layer from this API that I'd like to see in order to ensure that unmanaged resources are properly being released.

**The question is if I'm right in my understanding of this:**

> Given that the application layer no longer references an object from the managed wrapper, there's no way that underlying native objects used by that managed object can ever be released **until an exposed cleanup method explicitly does so**.

Am I correct in that?

Comment: You are asking about Marshal.ReleaseComObject().  Plenty of hits on it when you type that in the search box.  And no, using it is not a good idea unless the COM object interface is very simple.  Leave it up to the garbage collector to get this consistently right.  GC.Collect() if you have memory problems.

Comment: @Hans: Good **answer**. Change it to that from comment and get well deserved creds. ;-)

Comment: @Hans: Actually, `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`isn't exposed in Silverlight. :-(

Comment: Yes, not terribly surprising.  Well, good, something you don't have to worry about then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not quite correct.  When the garbage collector collects managed types that are referencing the COM types those references will be dereferenced using the COM `Release` call.  At ths point the unmanaged resources will be released assuming nothing else is reference the COM object instance.

However unless you are calling `GC.Collect()` (a fairly draconian thing to do) then it is possible for those unmanaged resource are held onto for far, far longer than necessary.

Comment: Ahhh, I see! That call to the COM object `Release()` function is exactly what I was missing. So the COM wrapper does it automatically, then? How nifty!